# Tool to convert indented text to work breakdown structure

Tags: gratis, file-converter

Does anyone knows a gratis (and open source if possible) tool to convert indented text to a work breakdown structure (or mindmap)? I know of text2mindmap but the output mindmap is stacked vertically and lacks personalisation.

Comment: What OS?  Recommendation for gratis or commercial software?

Comment: Free online or free for Windows and/or Linux